# How can I most productively check for overlaps between ETF holdings?

Tags: etf

My grandparents just realized that NASDAQ and S&P500 overlap as [listed in this Quora post dated May 11 2017](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-companies-in-the-NASDAQ-that-are-part-of-the-S-P-500). How can they see  overlaps more productively than copying and pasting each index's page to Excel, then using some Excel tool? Your recommendations must list all

1. overlaps
2. stocks that don't overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one that popped up from a Google of [ETF Fund Overlap](https://www.etfrc.com/funds/overlap.php).  I have no clue how reliable it is.  It appears that the membership is free.

Comment: This tool doesn't find any ETFs

Answer (score 1):

If you sign up for a free account, you can use the Morningstar "[Instant XRay](https://www.morningstar.com/instant-x-ray)" tool to see detailed total by-stock holdings (as well as higher level statistics) from your portfolio of any number of mutual funds.

Comment: Does the Morningstar "Instant XRay" list what overlaps and not?